# ¿Como puedo crear un evento cuando cambie el contenido de un fichero?

Tags: php, nodejs

Tengo un fichero donde escribo el resultado de unas ejecuciones de programa (OK | NO OK) y me gustaria crear un evento o ser capaz de detectar cuando cambia su valor para así poder actualizar los valores en una interfaz web.
He intentado mediante node.js fs.watchfile pero no soy capaz de incluir en el tag  el codigo para implementarlo.

```
<script>
    fs = require('fs');
    fs.watch("prueba.txt", function (event, fileName)
    {
        console.log("Event: " + event);
        console.log(fileName + "\n");
    });
</script>
```

No me devuelve nada cuando hago cambios en el documento

Comment: Puedes compartir el código que has intentado hacer?

Comment: Ya he añadido el código!

Comment: Eso es un `<script>` en una página HTML. ¿Entiendes que por motivos de seguridad un `script` en un navegador no tiene acceso directo al sistema de archivos del `host`?. Además, `node` está pensado para trabajar del lado servidor, por lo tanto o me estoy perdiendo algo o tu intento de correr un módulo de `node` en un `script` de una página nunca va a salir como lo esperas. El fichero en cuestión lo tienes en el Servidor, por lo que logro entender, y deseas actualizar la vista (frontend) cuando el servidor (backend) detecte cambios sobre el fichero. ¿Es correcto?

Comment: Correcto, como podria hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Según el código que has pegado lo estas haciendo mal, porque **nodejs es solo lado servidor** aunque tambien sea javascript.

Respecto a tu duda de como puedes detectar los cambios.

Has empezado bien, tu código esta bien, pero no lo has puesto en el sitio correcto. Y creo que `watch` no es  el metodo correcto, ya que de momento es inestable

Te sugiero utilizar [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar)

### Instalacion

`npm install chokidar` o `yarn add chokidar`

Después en tu archivo `.js` simplemente vas a escuchar los cambios.

```
const chokidar = require('chokidar');

chokidar.watch('./index.html').on('change', (event, path) => {
  console.log(event, path);
});
```

Chokidar tambien nos da información muy útil, tal como  que fecha se ha modificado, cuando se creo y etc...

Respecto a enviarlo a la la página web, lo mejor sería que utilizarás [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) que esta de forma nativa en el navegado.

Para el servidor necesitas utilizar algo [así](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodejs-websocket)

Espero que te haya ayudado en con almenos alguna duda.

Comment: Ya he instalado chokidar, ahora creo un fichero .js en el servidor con el codigo que has añadido y en el .`hphp como puedo obtener la informacion?

Comment: Se puede hacer de muchas maneras, por ejemplo una conexion socket entre el php(cliente) y nodejs(servidor) o hacer la peticion http al servidor php a un recurso(url) en concreto. Por otra parte te recomiendo abrir otra pregunta ya que inicialmente el problema estaba en poder detectar los cambios en un fichero.